# Managing user file uploads - Avoiding ghosts... - CMS/PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, file-upload

i've thinking about various ways of handling file uploads in a sort of CMS. I write here because i am not satisfied with what i've got right now...

**The problem**

Uhmm, lets call it the tumblr way ;-) The user shall be able to upload a file or several files directly without a file management view or s.th like that. The bottom side is that if he deletes the file in the WYSIWYG editor the file stays on the server. In my case there is not only a WYSIWYG editor also a media module...

**The question**

Is there  a best practice for handling this? I've never programmed s.th like that. Would you store the filenames in a MySQL table, would you use a cron job to check if the files are really used in the document?

ANY ADVICE WOULD BE REALLY APRECIATED!!!

Muchissimas Gracias y Saludos!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use a cron job that runs once a day and cleans up any orphan uploaded files (orphans older that x days).

I admit, I'm curious about other ppl approaches.

Comment: Thats what i am trying right now also ;-)ORPHANS... That was the english name i was looking for ;-) Maybe this will help me finding an article about this issue ;-) THx ;-)

Comment: It's a good solution, but you'll have to parse each record in your database looking for image tags, parsing the source and then finding the ones that are not in the database?
I don't think this is the right approach, maybe you should start working with a cloud-based hosting service like Amazon's.

Answer (score 0):

Why so much hassle for some additional space used? Hard drive space shouldn't be a concern, since it's so cheap. And even if it were not, the images are very lightweight resources.

The only problems I can imagine is that your CMS's users are uploading very large files. In that case, you should process the image before saving them, lowering the quality and the size.

I think a cron job would be more CPU intensive than letting some 'ghosts' files.

However, you could try to catch when an image is deleted, but then again, it could be more trouble.

Comment: Unfortunatly they can also upload videos and furthermore are the created documents kept for a very long time...